# Refactor SCSS with step-down

Tags: sass

Let's say I want to achieve this:

```
#page {
  p {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  #form {
    p {
    color: gray;
    }
  }
}
```

You will notice that the `p` in all `#page` is supposed to have the general style. But `#page #form` should inherit the general `p` except the `color`.

Is there a better way to write this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, [there is no way to restore the "default" value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Common_CSS_Questions#How_do_I_restore_the_default_value_of_a_property.3F) for a style property.

You can restrict the `#page p` styles to only those paragraphs which are direct descendants of `#page` with `#page > p`, otherwise `#page p` will necessarily match all paragraphs which `#page #form p` matches. The `#page p` styles *will* be applied to those elements, and if you want to undo them with `#page #form p`, you'll have to explicitly specify the styles as you want them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @extend, but not on inherited selectors.

You could use an @extend-only selector like so:

```
#page {
    %common_p {
        margin: 10px 20px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    p {
        @extend %common_p;
    }

    #form {
        p {
            @extend %common_p;
            color: gray;
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs as

```
#page p, #page #form p {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px; }
#page #form p {
  color: gray; }
```

I hope this accomplishes what you are desiring!

I am not sure if this is better though, as due to the cascade, any p tags inside #form would already also get #page's p tag. E.g. they would get the margin and padding and color, but color would be overwritten.

This simply forces that to take place, even if cascading wasn't occurring (e.g. if #form existed outside of #page). If that was the case, then this technique would be better as SASS would combine the styles to make the output less repetitive.

You can read more about what @extend is doing at http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders